# I need to perform an action based on which radio button is selected (by jQuery), but neither jQuery's click or change method is doing what I want

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the callback of a HttpRequest I have, I run this jQuery code:

```
$("input[value='"+data.notetype+"']").click();
```

So the radio button with the value of data.notetype is selected. This works fine. But I need to perform an action based on what button is now selected.

If I use the change() method like this

```
$("input[name='note_type']").change(function () { 
   var clicked = $("input[name='note_type']:checked").val()
   alert(clicked);
});
```

it works fine when I click on the radio buttons, but when the radio button is set by the first line of code above, nothing happens.

If I use the click() method like this

```
$("input[name='note_type']").change(function () { 
  var clicked = $("input[name='note_type']:checked").val()
  alert(clicked);
});
```

it works fine when I click on the radio buttons, but when the radio button is set by the first line of code above, the message box shows the value of the radio button that **was** selected, not the one it is changing to.

Can anyone let me know how to fix this problem? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[name='note_type']").click(function () { 
  var clicked = $(this).val();
  alert(clicked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for this problem, I think this will help you

For example following is your html

```
<input type="radio" name="some_name" value="1"> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="some_name" value="2"> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="some_name" value="3"> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="some_name" value="4"> 4 <br />
```

Try following jquery for this html

```
$('input[type=radio]').bind('click', function() { alert( $(this).val() ); });
```

I hope this will help